# USB bug which locks the kernel

Tags: usb, kernel, lock

I manage a few remote machines installed at a manufacturing facility, which run Ubuntu 18.04. For months I had seen unexpected kernel locks, which I could not explain. By locks I mean that the machine completely dies. The graphical screen and keyboard freezes. I cannot ping or connect through ssh during the locks. The only way of making the machine come back is through a power off/on sequence. After rebooting I cannot find anything meaningful about the lock in the logs. The machine is a good quality one with a 6-core Xeon, ECC memory, etc. Exact the same problem happens in multiple machines.

A few days ago I was able to create a sequence of events that produce the locks in a couple of minutes. These events have to do with USB 2.0 interrupt I/O on USB devices connected at 12 Mbits/s. It is necessary to have at least 36 devices connected to reproduce the problem easily, which I cannot do from where I am. The machines are in a country other than the one I live, and my physical access to them is not possible due to COVID-19 restrictions.

Due to company guidelines, I cannot upgrade the kernel, which is: Linux version 5.0.0-37-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-023) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019. There is no special USB drivers installed. However, there is a NVIDIA manufacturer driver installed, which I installed using the Ubuntu regular tools for non-free software. All USB I/O is done by a regular user (the device group is set to the user group by udev).

During the test phase, we tried Kernel 5.3.0-62-generic, which had the same behavior. My guess is that, for a regular user, this bug rarely manifests itself and it may be there for a long time.

I would like to figure out exactly where the problem is and I am looking for your guidance.

Is there a way of getting meaningful information about the lock when it happens? How to figure out where the kernel is hanging, considering I am remote?

Additional information:

Just to be clear, we have two machines with exact the same problem. One is still running kernel 5.3.0-62 and the other 5.0.0-37. Here is the information I collected:

## cat /proc/cpuinfo

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2133 CPU @ 3.60GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x2006906
cpu MHz     : 1200.306
cache size  : 8448 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 7200.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
....

processor   : 11
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2133 CPU @ 3.60GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x2006906
cpu MHz     : 1200.379
cache size  : 8448 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 11
initial apicid  : 11
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 7200.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

## free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        860M         29G        7.1M        1.3G         29G
Swap:           15G          0B         15G
```

## lsb_release  -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

## cat /proc/version

```
Linux version 5.3.0-62-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020
```

## sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

## lshw -C memory

```
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 1
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 4
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8448KiB
       capacity: 8448KiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 6
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
       capabilities: ecc
       configuration: errordetection=ecc
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Registered (Buffered) 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: HMA81GR7CJR8N-VK
          vendor: Hynix
          physical id: 0
          serial: 33B2CDD7
          slot: CPU0-DIMM1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: CPU0-DIMM2
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Registered (Buffered) 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: HMA81GR7CJR8N-VK
          vendor: Hynix
          physical id: 2
          serial: 33B2CD95
          slot: CPU0-DIMM3
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: CPU0-DIMM4
     *-bank:4
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 4
          slot: CPU0-DIMM5
     *-bank:5
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Registered (Buffered) 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: HMA81GR7CJR8N-VK
          vendor: Hynix
          physical id: 5
          serial: 33B2CDD8
          slot: CPU0-DIMM6
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:6
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 6
          slot: CPU0-DIMM7
     *-bank:7
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Registered (Buffered) 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: HMA81GR7CJR8N-VK
          vendor: Hynix
          physical id: 7
          serial: 33B2CCC4
          slot: CPU0-DIMM8
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: HP
       physical id: 5
       version: P61 v01.76
       date: 04/22/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90420000-90423fff
```

## lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DMI3 Registers (rev 04)
00:04.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:04.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 04)
00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E MM/Vt-d Configuration Registers (rev 04)
00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2025 (rev 04)
00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Device 2026 (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 04)
00:08.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 04)
00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset SATA RAID Controller
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C422 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SPI Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X111SL PCIe-to-PCI Reversible Bridge (rev 02)
02:04.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 62)
02:04.1 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 62)
02:04.2 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 65)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X111SL PCIe-to-PCI Reversible Bridge (rev 02)
06:04.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 62)
06:04.1 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 62)
06:04.2 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 65)
14:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04)
14:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2034 (rev 04)
14:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers (rev 04)
14:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Device 2036 (rev 04)
14:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:08.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:08.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:08.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:08.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:09.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0e.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0e.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0e.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:1d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:1d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:1d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:1d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
14:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
14:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
14:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
14:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
14:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
14:1e.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
14:1e.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
15:00.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X111SL PCIe-to-PCI Reversible Bridge (rev 02)
16:04.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 62)
16:04.1 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 62)
16:04.2 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 65)
20:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04)
20:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2034 (rev 04)
20:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers (rev 04)
20:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Device 2036 (rev 04)
20:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2066 (rev 04)
20:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2066 (rev 04)
20:0a.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2040 (rev 04)
20:0a.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2041 (rev 04)
20:0a.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2042 (rev 04)
20:0a.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2043 (rev 04)
20:0a.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2044 (rev 04)
20:0a.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2045 (rev 04)
20:0a.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2046 (rev 04)
20:0a.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2047 (rev 04)
20:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2048 (rev 04)
20:0b.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2049 (rev 04)
20:0b.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 204a (rev 04)
20:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 204b (rev 04)
20:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2040 (rev 04)
20:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2041 (rev 04)
20:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2042 (rev 04)
20:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2043 (rev 04)
20:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2044 (rev 04)
20:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2045 (rev 04)
20:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2046 (rev 04)
20:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2047 (rev 04)
20:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2048 (rev 04)
20:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2049 (rev 04)
20:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 204a (rev 04)
20:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 204b (rev 04)
21:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL [Quadro P400] (rev a1)
21:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
2c:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04)
2c:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port C (rev 04)
2c:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port D (rev 04)
2c:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2034 (rev 04)
2c:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers (rev 04)
2c:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Device 2036 (rev 04)
2c:12.0 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 04)
2c:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 04)
2c:12.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 04)
2c:15.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 04)
2c:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 04)
2c:16.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 04)
2c:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 04)
2d:00.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X111SL PCIe-to-PCI Reversible Bridge (rev 02)
2e:04.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 62)
2e:04.1 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 62)
2e:04.2 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 65)
```

Thank you for your answer.

The chances of having a memory problem are too small: these are two brand new machines with exactly the same behavior.

Each set of 18 USB devices is connected to a 10-Amp.-power-supply powered HUB. Each hub has its own USB 2.0 root, I mean, I installed multiple USB 2.0 PCI express expansion cards, and only one port of each expansion card is used for each HUB. I do not believe I have a problem there either.

About BIOS, I cannot see, due to my lack of knowledge, how it could affect an expansion card after Linux takes over. I would appreciate a clarification about the BIOS mechanism that would interfere on the way the kernel access the interface.

However, above all that, a change in the application program avoids the kernel lock. So, a regular user, running a user application with read/write access to /dev/bus/usb/XXX/XXX can lock the kernel if he access the devices very quickly. A simple change there, and a PC which previously locked in a couple of minutes after power up, will not lock in 72 hours, as we observed. I mean that the application is basically the same, and the only difference would be delays of a few milliseconds, which will avoid kernel locks. An additional clarification is important: no delay was introduced between accesses to the same device. But if the application access all devices at the same time (without delays) a kernel lock will happen after a few minutes.

I really think I should touch the kernel, and figure out exactly why it is locking. If the application program submits too many URBs at the same time we have a good chance of getting a kernel lock. Delays between URB submissions will avoid the lock.

My point is that simple ioctl calls to USB devices should not break the kernel. I need help to address the kernel issue. The problem is difficult to reproduce because it needs many devices connected to it which are available in a place I do not have physical access to, due to COVID-19 travel restrictions.

Any clue about how to debug this kernel issue?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. What processor? What version Ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema : 18.04 and Xeon, 6 core. OP: What generation of Xeon? Give us the model number.

Comment: The computer will freeze, if it runs out of memory

Comment: @heynnema

I added the information requested to my question

Comment: 36 devices at 12 Mbits/Sec is likely at the limit of the USB 2 bandwidth, once overheads are included.

Comment: When adding text to your answer, you may need to make it human-readable by: selecting the pasted text, and then click on the {} icon. I already edited your question for you :-)

Comment: @DougSmythies When the bandwidth is exceeded, the device will not enumerate, I mean, no /dev/bus/usb/xxx/xxx will be created, and the application will not have access to it. However there are only 18 devices per USB root port, plus the hubs. And all of them enumerate. This is not supposed to lock the kernel, though.

Comment: Are you saying that this issue occurs regardless, but can be made much more probable by increasing the number of devices? i.e. it is likely some timing window or the like, simply made more probable by increasing the number of times per unit time that whatever, interrupt or something, occurs. If there is nothing in the `/var/log/*` files, I would try to monitor a bunch of stuff, interrupts, temp, load, memory use, in SSH sessions leading up to the freeze. I do not know what to look for until we see it.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Your HP has BIOS version: P61 v01.76

I need the EXACT make/model # to be able to check for a newer BIOS. If you have the `HP Z4 G4 workstation` (P61), then a newer BIOS, version 2.59, dated Sept 4, 2020, is available [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-z4-g4-workstation/16449890).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memory**

I also need to check your memory configuration via the User Manual, as it may not be correct.

According to [this](https://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA7-2219ENW), your memory is installed correctly.

[image]

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**USB**

There may be too many USB devices on one USB controller. Most computers have more than one USB hub, and possibly, connecting some of the USB devices to USB ports on different USB hubs might make a difference.

Use `lsusb` to view your USB hubs.

Use `lsusb -tv` to determine where your USB devices are connected.

Move some USB devices to other USB ports if possible.

You may also have a USB power issue, which might be solved by the use of an external **powered** USB hub(s).

Comment: I need help to debug the Kernel and find the problem.

Comment: @user1145837  If I've got the correct hardware model #, why not try the BIOS update, and the USB troubleshooting first. You may not need to debug the kernel... and you probably won't get that kind of help here anyway.

Comment: @user1145837 Please don't modify an answer that you didn't write. Use either comments, or, if your comments are lengthy, do an edit to your original question. Thanks!

Comment: @user1145837 The BIOS operates the entire under pinnings of the computer. Any malfunction there can cause all kinds of problems, including PCI/PCIe and USB problems.

Comment: It is difficult to update the BIOS remotely. If I have a good reason to believe that the kernel would stop dyeing because of the BIOS, I would do that. Please give me a reason and I will do it. I have been using Linux for more than 20 years. My experience tells me that, when there is a problem, some devices may stop working. I've never seen one breaking a stable kernel. And these are simple devices: all interaction with them are done through 64-byte interrupt packets.

Comment: I am sorry about modifying your answer. I am new to this site.

Comment: @user1145837 re: *"If I have a good reason to believe that the kernel would stop dyeing because of the BIOS, I would do that. Please give me a reason and I will do it."*... when the basics (the BIOS in this case) aren't right, you can't even begin to try and troubleshoot anything else. ie: the engine in my car isn't running correctly... and the oil hasn't been changed in 10 years. answer: change the oil first.

Comment: Any suggestions about where I can get Kernel support?

Comment: @AlSentieri Sorry, no I don't. But again... I think you're taking on the wrong approach as a first step to solving your problem.

Comment: Well, if it were me, and I did not have the latest BIOS, that would indeed be step 1, always. I could not find a change log for the BIOS that @heynnema pointed to, but it be worth a review.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for the backup. The change log is viewable by flipping down the triangle that appears just to the left of the BIOS update info. Problem is that although it shows previous BIOS updates, it doesn't go back as far as what BIOS they have now. Since I haven't gotten any confirmation from OP that I've got the correct model #, I may be pointing at the wrong web page anyway.

Comment: @AlSentieri Status please...